# Update new column of table with it's previous column value and join id with duplicate values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table with 3 columns id,name,new_column So my requirement is to add name column values to new_column but if namae column have duplicate values then in new_column values should be combination of id+name values

Table structure

```
id  name   new_name (empty column)

1  aaa
2  bbb
3  ccc
4  ddd
5  aaa
6  eee
7  ccc
```

Now expected output

id  name      new_name (empty column)

```
1  aaa     aaa
2  bbb     bbb
3  ccc     ccc     
4  ddd     ddd
5  aaa     5aaa (due to duplicate value id + name )
6  eee     eee
7  ccc     7ccc (due to duplicate value id + name )
```

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine the names in an *update*, then you can use:

```
update t join
       (select t.*, 
               row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as seqnum
        from t
       ) tt
       on tt.id = t.id
    set t.name = concat(t.id, t.name)
    where tt.seqnum > 1;
```

Or without window functions:

```
update t join
       (select name, min(id) as min_id 
        from t
        group by name
       ) tt
       on t.name = tt.name and t.id > tt.min_id
    set t.name = concat(t.id, t.name);
```

Comment: can u please explain this query,it is working as per requirement I need some guidenece about this

Comment: Linoffcan u explian why u have used min is it necessary to use min()

Comment: @user_1234 . . . Because the rows seem to be ordered by `id` and you want to treat the first one differently.

Answer (score 1):

If your MySQL version support `ROW_NUMBER` + window function, you can try to use that make a seq number then use `CASE WHEN` to judgment whether duplicate

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   id int,
   name varchar(50)
);


    
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,'aaa');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (2,'bbb');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (3,'ccc');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (4,'ddd');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (5,'aaa');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (6,'eee');
INSERT INTO T VALUES (7,'ccc');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT name, 
      CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN name ELSE CONCAT(id,name) END new_name 
FROM (
  SELECT  *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id) rn
  FROM T
) t1
ORDER BY id;
```

| name | new_name |
| --- | --- |
| aaa | aaa |
| bbb | bbb |
| ccc | ccc |
| ddd | ddd |
| aaa | 5aaa |
| eee | eee |
| ccc | 7ccc |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bZg8sMWa9AT6aHbqGjKcbd/1)

Comment: can we update instead of insert because we have to put those value in same table and infront of name column

Comment: @user_1234 https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bZg8sMWa9AT6aHbqGjKcbd/2 you can try to use inner join and update like the link